# How to pass onClick function to Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, delegates, parameter-passing

I want to modularize the usage of my class but I have problem in passing function. I want to be able to pass an **OnClickListener** from 1 activity to this **CoachmarkActivity**.

I tried 2 different method:
 1. Passing an OnClickListener to Intent
 2. Passing a class, FollowUpClass, implements Serializable, which has method onClick.

You can see the code below. It is not complete code, but you should be able to comprehend this.

```
public class CoachmarkActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String RES_LAYOUT = "RES-LAYOUT";
    public static final String LISTENER = "LISTENER";
    public static final String FOLLOW_UP = "FOLLOW-UP";

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {

        setContentView(getIntent.getIntExtra(RES_LAYOUT, R.layout.activity_default))

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        // 1ST ATTEMPT        
        // I want to modularize this
        OnClickListener onClickPassedFromIntent = (OnClickListener) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(LISTENER);
        button1.setOnClickListener(onClickPassedFromIntent);

        // 2ND ATTEMPT
        final FollowUpListener folllowup = (FollowUpListener) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(FOLLOW_UP);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override void onClick() {
                // !! Here is error, exception thrown
                folllowup.onClick();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Public method to be used in other activity.
     * Invocation wanna be:
     *   CoachmarkActivity.startThisActivity(getActivity(), R.layout.coachmark1, new OnClickListener() {
     *      @Override void onClick() {
     *          // Do something
     *      }
     *   });
     */
    public static void startThisActivity(Context context, int resId, OnClickListener listener) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CoachmarkActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(RES_LAYOUT, resId);
        // !! Line below is error, onClickListener is not serializable, no method can accomadate below
        intent.putExtra(LISTENER, listener);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Public method to be used in other activity.
     * Invocation wanna be:
     *   CoachmarkActivity.startThisActivity(getActivity(), R.layout.coachmark1, new FollowUpListener() {
     *      @Override void onClick() {
     *          // Do something
     *      }
     *   });
     */
    public static void startThisActivity(Context context, int resId, FollowUpListener folllowup) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CoachmarkActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(RES_LAYOUT, resId);
        intent.putExtra(FOLLOW_UP, followup);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The abstract class:

```
public abstract class FollowUpListener implements Serializable {
    public abstract void onClick();
}
```

The problems are stated in the comment in source code above, with tag "!!" (Just CTRL+F "!!"). What I want to do is like passing a Delegate object (function in form of variable) in C#, but in Android Java.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me the purpose of sending the onClickListener from one Activity to anther?

Comment: I feel something is not correct here. Can you simply describe the series of event for a button click?

Comment: What the exception have you got in the second case? `// !! Here is error, exception thrown`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add a `Serializable` extra to your Intent, but `OnClickListener` does not implement that interface. You can achieve what you want by creating a class that implements both of the interfaces you need.

```
private class SerializableClickListener implements View.OnClickListener, Serializable {

    @Override public void onClick() {
        // TODO handle click
    }
}
```

However, just because you can doesn't mean you should. Sending a click listener to another activity is a horrible code smell, and you should really rethink how you could do this via Intents/Broadcasts.

Comment: Any idea about this?
I mean, I want to make the act of closing the CoachmarkAcrivity (the onClick) become the responsibility of it's invoker activity, thus I would reduce the clutter of the CoachmarkActivity code (like: switch, case inside CoachmarkActivity)

Comment: I think this is ok, providing your OnClickListener has no dependencies in the target activity. As FractalWrench has said you could get a "horrible code smell".... but if the onClickListener has no dependencies to the CoachmarkActivity, the "smell" should be fragrant and not pongy...You may code without guilt...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to pass the OnlclickListener and I couldn't. then I tried this solution.

1. I made a static click listener variable in a GlobalData class

   ```
   public static View.OnClickListener btn;
   ```
2. Then when I call the startactivity to go to another activity I did this.

   ```
    GlobalData.btn = new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Listern action
                        }
                    };
   c.startActivity(new Intent(c, DialogActivity.class));
   ```
3. Then in the second activity, I can set the static listener reference which I used to assign a listener object in the first activity.

   ```
   b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(GlobalData.btn!=null){
                            GlobalData.btn1.onClick(v);
                        }
                        finish();
                    }
                });
   ```

I didn't use it directly as a parameter so I can do other stuff in the second activity listener. this worked for me.

But you have to think more because you are using a static reference. this is not a 100% solution. but it's worth trying.